# Computer enclosure with high MERV furnace filter

Tags: enclosure

I am sick of paying US$1000 a year for a professional commercial datacenter colo for merely a hobbyist Minecraft / Space Engineers / Factorio gaming server that makes no money and is not run to make a profit.

I would instead like to build a gaming server that will sit hundreds of miles away from me in someone's closet or basement on their Google fiber, and I want this mini-server to be as close to zero maintenance as possible for the friend acting as my server host.

I know that dust is the death of technology, and this thing is going to run 24x7 for years in a mostly unmonitored location, so it needs extreme reliability and dust protection.

I want to use a professional HVAC high-end deep-pleat furnace filter with high particulate retention, not the cheap blue US$1 filters that let fine dust through.

Something like this 20" x 21" x 5" deep MERV 16 filter:
https://www.filtersfast.com/P-Lennox-X8790-MERV-16-Air-Filter-Replacement.asp?kpid=X8790

This high grade professional filter is likely going to take a bit of static pressure to drive air through it as it builds a dust layer, so the case likely needs more than the typical low-pressure axial fans, possibly a small squirrel cage or centrifugal horticultural blower.

Though I am also trying to go for something quiet, so the blower likely needs to be of a large diameter, to be slow enough and still have sufficient static air pressure.

I have spent many months trying to find a super-low maintenance computer case or enclosure like this, and so far it appears no such thing exists. It probably would have to be custom manufactured in a makerspace on a CNC router table or with a plasma cutter.

Any ideas?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not just by time on a server in a datacenter rather than dealing with the hardware yourself if you're not going to have physical access to it anyways? FYI, most "real" servers just sort of assume a fairly dust-free environment; it might be better to filter the dust externally rather than inside the server.

Comment: As stated, already buying time in a datacenter for US$1000 per year. Equipment spec is too high and usage is too complicated for a cheap low-end virtualized single-game-process colo. Need Ubuntu, CPU with high single core performance, 64gig memory, and shell access, to run about 6-8 heavily modded Minecrafts that each need 4-6gb memory (Infinity, Hermit, etc) linked by IRC, Discord node.js connector, KVM VM for Windows 10....... meanwhile personally I live in the boondocks, 1.5 / 0.25 meg DSL in a rural area, so I can't host it myself.

Comment: You said you were paying for space in a colo, not for server time itself. I don't know exactly what specs you need, but it's free to check how much an [EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/reserved-instances/pricing/), [Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/), or [Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/pricing/) instance would cost. What are we looking at total? 16 cores at maybe a Passmark of 1500 per core, 64 GB of RAM, 4TB of hot spinning storage, and 1Gb/s up/down?

Comment: In any case, I'm still wondering if it'd be better to filter the air in the room rather than as it enters the server–especially since that'd allow you to use 2 or 3 gen old off-the-self servers for much, much cheaper than building your own. Plus, it'll be designed and validated for 24/7/365 operation, all while giving you server-grade features, like allowing you to monitor remotely and change low level settings using IPMI.